# MAUI Blazor when taping the Push Notification the splash screen hangs

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui, maui-blazor

I am creating a Maui Blazor app to receive push notification with FCM.
I am using this example.
https://github.com/mistrypragnesh40/PushNotificationDemoMAUI

I am receiving the push notifications on both Android and iOS.
The issue is only on Android when I tap on the notification. The purple splash screen comes up but no .net image, just a purple screen. It hangs forever and does not load the app.

If the app is closed or is active, tapping on the notification brings up the app just fine. It only occurs when you start the app, then "minimize" it, then tap on the notification.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does the `If the app active, tapping on the notification brings up the app just fine`. It creates a new instance of the App?

Comment: No, it does not start a new instance. If I run it in debug, I see that the OnNewIntent get executed in the MainActivity.

Comment: What package about FCM did you use? And did the OnNewIntent method gt executed when the app was minimized? Did you try to add the LaunchMode = SingleTask or LaunchMode = SingleInstance for the MainActivity?

Comment: Setting LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop in the MainActivity solved the issue. Thank you so much for you help

Comment: You can welcome and I posted it as an answer to help the others who meet the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the MainActivity's default launch mode is

> "standard"

> The default mode. The system creates a new instance of the activity in
> the task it was started from and routes the intent to it. The activity
> can be instantiated multiple times, each instance can belong to
> different tasks, and one task can have multiple instances.

Set the `LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop` will resovle it.